# how to get the tapped node of a 3d model in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libGDX library for loading 3d models in android. How can I know which node has been tapped by the user.

For exp- I have a 3d model of a car. If user touches the tyre of the car, tyre info should be shown.

**Please suggest, if there is any more suitable library for this purpose.**

Answer (score 0):

You need some basic vector math to do this. There are a few approaches:

1. find the projection of the node onto the screen and determine if the touch position is close enough. This works fine for objects without irregularities in their shape. `camera.project()` is your friend here.
2. find the projection of the touch position in 3d space: trace a line from the camera near pane to the far pane and determine if you hit any meshes. This is an expensive but more accurate method. `camera.unproject()` will help here.

Box2D might have more helpful functionality, but I haven't played with that library myself.